# Sub-titles for matrix columns in table

Tags: matlab, matrix

Here's my toy example:

```
t = table([1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9],[10,11,12;13,14,15;16,17,18]);
t.Properties.VariableNames = {'system1', 'system2'};
t.Properties.RowNames = {'obs1', 'obs2', 'obs3'};
```

I am wondering if it's possible to assign sub titles to the three columns of every variable, such as `{'min', 'mean', 'max'}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put those subtitles within the variables using a cell array like this:

```
t = table({'min', 'mean', 'max';  1,  2,  3;  4,  5,  6;  7,  8,  9},...
          {'min', 'mean', 'max'; 10, 11, 12; 13, 14, 15; 16, 17, 18});
t.Properties.VariableNames = {'system1', 'system2'};
t.Properties.RowNames = {'.','obs1', 'obs2', 'obs3'};  
%if you don't like dot (.) as a row name, replace it with char(8203) to have nameless row
```

which will give:

```
t =    
  4×2 table
                    system1                     system2         
            ________________________    ________________________

    .       'min'    'mean'    'max'    'min'    'mean'    'max'
    obs1    [  1]    [   2]    [  3]    [ 10]    [  11]    [ 12]
    obs2    [  4]    [   5]    [  6]    [ 13]    [  14]    [ 15]
    obs3    [  7]    [   8]    [  9]    [ 16]    [  17]    [ 18]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for functional solution (e.g. `t.system1.min`) You can nest sub-tables for `system1` and `system2` with `{'min', 'mean', 'max'}` as Variable Names. Visually it won't be as useful as other solutions.

```
dat1 = [1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9];
dat2 = [10,11,12;13,14,15;16,17,18];

s1 = table(dat1(:,1),dat1(:,2),dat1(:,3));
s2 = table(dat2(:,1),dat2(:,2),dat2(:,3));

s1.Properties.VariableNames = {'min','mean','max'};
s1.Properties.RowNames = {'obs1', 'obs2', 'obs3'};
s2.Properties.VariableNames = {'min','mean','max'};
s2.Properties.RowNames = {'obs1', 'obs2', 'obs3'};

t = table(s1,s2);
t.Properties.VariableNames = {'system1', 'system2'};
t.Properties.RowNames = {'obs1', 'obs2', 'obs3'};
```